# Regex in javascript - should not allow consecutive parenthesis , consecutive + sign and consecutive -sign

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate a **phone number** which can be **any format**. but it should not allow consecutive hyphens, parenthesis and + signs. In addition no special characters and alphabets should not be allowed. I am not that much good at regex.

**Allowed will be:**
single       -, ( , ), (), + and spaces.

I have tried with the following regex
**(?!-)(?!.*--)(([0-9-,(),+]{0,25}))**

through this i am able to restrict consecutive hyphens.

Can anyone help on this?

eg:

```
+765766-8776(090)    --> valid format
7-(98665             --> valid 
123456789098880998   --> valid
85786 87787          --> valid
+165667687777878(989)--> valid
+1 97877-88888 (090) --> valid

----()90             --> Invalid as consecutive hyphens
ffgffgtgf98-         --> invalid as characters are there
#$%%5                --> invalid as special characters are there
+++++++++898988++++++++76768 -->invalid as consecutive plus sign
989(((090))))                -->invalid as consecutive parenthesis
```

Comment: no that is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^(?:(?:([-()+ ])(?!\1))|\d)+$/`

- Start of string
- - Either of these:
  - Special character, not immediately followed by the same character
  - A number
  - (* repeat as many times as needed)
- End of string

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
^(?!.*(?:([()+-]){2}))[0-9()+\s-]{0,25}$
```

Comment: hi, i have tested with http://regexstorm.net/tester regex tester, it is selecting the consecutive + signs also

Comment: @shanthi_karthika What is the input you used for testing?

Comment: +++++++++898988++++++++76768 and 
989(((090))) and ----()90

Comment: @shanthi_karthika i dont see it.. check [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f!.*(%3f%3a(%5b()%2b-%5d)%7b2%7d))%5b0-9()%2b%5cs-%5d%7b0%2c25%7d%24&i=%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b898988%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b76768%0d%0a989(((090)))%0d%0a%2b2-84823%2b1342%2b1452341%0d%0a----()90%0d%0a&o=m)

Comment: ya rght. but when i tired with some more inputs along with this. Please check this [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f!.*(%3f%3a(%5b()%2b-%5d)%7b2%7d))%5b0-9()%2b%5cs-%5d%7b0%2c25%7d&i=%2b765766-8776(090)+++%0d%0a----()90++++++++++++%0d%0a7-(98665++++++++++++%0d%0a123456789098880998+++%0d%0a85786+87787++++++++++%0d%0a%2b165667687777878(989)%0d%0affgffgtgf+++++++++++%0d%0a%23%24%25%255+++++++++++++++%0d%0a%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b898988%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b76768+%0d%0a989(((090)))%0d%0a98989.90909%0d%0a%2b91+876876767%40%23%23%24%40%23(090)%0d%0a)

Comment: @shanthi_karthika okay.. thats because you are using without multiline flag and without anchors